# Longtable across double page

Tags: longtable, double-sided

i would like to know how to make a LONGtable across a double page (I need 2 or more double pages for my data), like:

left page: Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4

right page: Column5 Column6 column7 Column8

The information of all 8 Columns is too wide to get it on one page (independet from using "landscape" or not), that´s why I want to split it on a double page.
A smaller font size is not solving the problem ("footnotesize" is the smallest font size that I prefer).
I found that, which looks like to solve my problem:

```
 \begin{spanrecto}
 \resizebox{16in}{!}{
  Span Content!}
 \end{spanrecto}
```

-> Link: [Equation across a double page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215852/equation-across-a-double-page)

But I dont know how to use that for longtables...

the documentclass is from here: [http://wwwpub.zih.tu-dresden.de/~fahan/tudscr/index.php](http://wwwpub.zih.tu-dresden.de/%7Efahan/tudscr/index.php)
I am using the following code (tudscrreprt is from my university):

```
\documentclass[cdfont=heavy, 11pt, oneside, numbers=noenddot]{tudscrreprt}
\begin{document}

\begin{footnotesize}
 \begin{longtable}[c]{r r r r r r r r}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \midrule
    \endhead
    Speciesname & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ \\
    Speciesname & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ \\
    Speciesname & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ \\
    Speciesname & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ \\
    Speciesname & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ \\
    Speciesname & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ \\
    Speciesname & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ \\
    Speciesname & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ & $1.7 \pm 0.8$ \\   
 \end{longtable}
\end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

I would be happy if somebody could help me, please :)

I hope I explained my problem in a understandable way...
Thank you!

Comment: An example code that is closer to your actual table would be more useful here. How exactly do the contents of the columns look like? Do they contain numbers, short words, equations, longer sentences...? Also, where did you find the tudscrreprt document class?

Comment: thanks for your comment, i hope the additional information is helpful

Comment: I just did some tests with the MWE you provided and unless the actual entries in the "speciesname"   columns, your column headers or the actual numbers in the other columns are exceptionally long, your table fits perfectly fine into the textwidth of a portrait oriented page, even when just reducing the font size to small. So, I can't really reproduce your issue.

Comment: If long speciesnames of column header cause your table to overflow, you could introduce linebreaks in the corresponding cells.

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: thank you for your help! Yes, with the given values it fits for one page, but the values can be higher like 250.1 +- 10.3 ...

Comment: Unfortunately I still have quite a hard time figuring out why your table would not fit onto a landscape page. Would you mind preparing an example in which you include one row in your table that just contains the widest entry of each column? With this example code one could better visualize how wide your entries really are and how much space your table needs. Probably there is a way to make the table fit without having to split it up.